# ASP.NET web app doesn't run correctly after upgrade from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I just updated my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app to .NET 6. It builds fine locally but I had all kinds of issues publishing to our IIS server. I usually publish using the dotnet CLI on our IIS server.

When I would do this it would build fine but throw a runtime exception for missing package references. Finally I attempted to publish locally on my development machine as a workaround then I moved all the files to our IIS server. I think this may be related to using an updated version of MSBuild. That's the only thing that changed in my publish process from before.

Anyway, now my app is running without throwing an exception using the workaround. However, now it is not behaving the same as pre-upgrade. The app works by monitoring a folder for file drops and then parses the new files and moves them to another folder. This relies on a FileSystemWatcher which worked fine before the upgrade.

Now when I drop a file into the monitored folder, my app starts eating memory and does not process the file. It doesn't throw any exceptions either.

My code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dashboards/HospitalDashboard", "");
        });

        // Probably need to set this to the right db depending on server as well.
        services.AddDbContext<HospitalDashboardContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(Environment.MachineName)));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                options.ModelBinderProviders.RemoveType<DateTimeModelBinderProvider>());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Visitors { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        CreateDbIfNotExists(host);

        InboxWatcher watcher = new InboxWatcher();

        var inboxTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            watcher.Watch();
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        FileCleaner fileCleaner = new FileCleaner();
        var fileCleanupTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            fileCleaner.ClearLogFiles();
            fileCleaner.DeleteExpiredFiles();
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

        Parser.Watch();
        host.Run();
    }

    private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<HospitalDashboardContext>();
                // Commented out due to using database migrations.
                //context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                if (!(context.Hospitals.Select(x => x).Any()))
                {
                    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Watch() method that is called from `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Watch()
{
        var tempPath = "C:\\SFTP_Root\\M1_out";

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = tempPath,
            Filter = "*.xml",
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
            IncludeSubdirectories = false,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        };

        watcher.Created += OnCreated;
}
```

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>Unit_Hospital_Time_Dashboard</RootNamespace>
        <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
        <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="5.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.5">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NuGet.CommandLine" Version="6.5.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I expected that because I upgraded my target framework and nuget packages that my application would run the same given it builds without errors. On our IIS server I installed the .NET 6 SDK and hosting package.

I've tried debugging but my breakpoint never hits in the `Watch()` method. The application just hangs. This happens locally and on the IIS server.

This is a separate but related issue that I'm hoping someone can provide a solution to solve the publish issues using dotnet CLI.

I tried the following:

- Delete bin/obj folders
- Clear nuget local cache
- Reference the complaining package directly
- Downgrade nuget packages and application back to .NET Core 3.1. This still didn't work and my application still was throwing the following exception upon running it on the server (this didn't happen locally)

  > Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography, Version=7.0.0.0
- This was temporarily solved by publishing from my development machine and copying over the files to the IIS server.

Here's the dotnet publish command I was running:

```
dotnet publish -o "C:\Dashboard Files\Dashboard Publish" 
       --self-contained -f net6.0 -r win-x64 -c Debug
```

Comment: You have quite a mix of dependencies here. I'm not sure why it's working fine locally but I would definitely start from removing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` nuget package (I believe it should be mentioned in some upgrade docs) and downgrading `System.Security` to `6.x.x` version.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reached end of life a while ago. You shouldn’t publish against it any more. Try to target `net6.0` please.

Comment: It looks like you are registering a new FileSystemWatcher every 30 second with the timer `inboxTimer` ?

Comment: Just to clear a few things up. The app does not work locally when I target net6.0. I get the same behavior as on the remote server. As soon as I revert back to netcore3.1 it works. I've got to be missing something in my upgrade process I just have no idea what.

Comment: Again - remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` package (it should have been removed when migrating from 2.x to 3.x). Downgrade dependencies like `System.Security.Cryptography.*` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` to 6x version (personally I would downgrade EF Core packages also).

Comment: Alright I removed those items and downgraded the dependencies and it seems to be running correctly locally. However, this is not the case when it's published to our IIS server. It's just hung up and not processing files. No windows logs or exceptions. Any ideas?